# Attaching RatingBar to notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, ratingbar

I have been looking for how to use a `RatingBar` in notification for a long time now , but as long as i know , `RatingBar` is not among `RemoteViews` even though in **API 31** some widgets and layouts are added as : `CheckBox` , `RadioButton` ,`RadioGroup`, `Switch` , add to that the existing `ProgressBar` but according to the
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews) descendants of these classes are not supported.

So , my question is , how google map has done it since a long time ago ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is their own component. its private , not in public

Comment: ok , maybe i have to look for something else